# Fetched Property in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

In my core data model, a `Person` has one or more `Cars`, specified by the unordered to-many relationship 'Cars'. Frequently, I need to retrieve a Person's cars ordered by `datePurchased`, or by `dateLastUsed`.

Until now, I have been adding my own method to `Person` for `carsByDatePurchased`. This uses a sort descriptor to sort the NSSet `cars` and return an NSArray.

Could/should I instead use a Fetched Property for this? I am experiencing some performance overhead using the sort descriptor every time I need the cars in a certain order, even going so far as implementing my own caching of `carsByDatePurchased`. It looks like the fetched property is cached for me - is that correct?

What are the limitations of a fetched property vs my own implementation?

And crucially, does the fetched property's value persist between executions? If I update the fetched property and save my context, is the value stored for the next time I launch the application?

Answer (score 4):

A fetched property will work, and indeed I used it in my own project with a Post->Comment relationship which needs to be sorted by 'date added index'.

There are a number of caveats: You cannot specify a sort descriptor in the visual editor and have to specify it in code.

I use something like this

```
    // Find the fetched properties, and make them sorted...
for (NSEntityDescription *entity in [_managedObjectModel entities])
{
    for (NSPropertyDescription *property in [entity properties])
    {
        if ([property isKindOfClass:[NSFetchedPropertyDescription class]])
        {
            NSFetchedPropertyDescription *fetchedProperty = (NSFetchedPropertyDescription *)property;
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [fetchedProperty fetchRequest];

            // Only sort by name if the destination entity actually has a "index" field
            if ([[[[fetchRequest entity] propertiesByName] allKeys] containsObject:@"index"])
            {
                NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"index"
                                                                           ascending:YES];

                [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName]];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In My Post entity I have a fetched property called "sortedComments" which is defined as:

```
post == $FETCH_SOURCE
```

where posts have a to-many "comments" relationship and comments have a "post" inverse

In opposition to the other answers here: The benefits of using a fetched property like this, is CoreData takes care of the caching and invalidating the cache as comments for a post or indeed the post that owns them changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to gain some performance, do your fetch with an NSFetchedResultsController and have it working with a cache. Next time you perform the same fetch, the fetch will be faster. In your particular name, you will have to cache names. Take a look at the NSFetchedResultsController [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: But would the cached results persist between launches? That's one crucial part I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes (padding because reply is not long enough)

Comment: Well well well. This might be the silver bullet. I will attempt this today. Just to be clear, you are suggesting using the NSFetchedResultsController *inside* my cardsByDatePurchased method? This method currently orders self.cars and returns the array - you are saying should fetch the cars and sort them using the results controller *instead* of using cars.self?

Comment: I notice immediately that the docs expect the FRC to be used to update a table view, and provides results formatted for that. But it's ok to use it just for it's caching mechanism (also the delegate for tracking changes will be useful)?

Comment: @BenPackard: A FRC is mainly used as a table view data source, but it is not restricted to that. But you have to implement as least one of the delegate methods to enable change tracking.

Comment: @MartinR is correct. You can use it for the memory tracking and the cache mechanism, because it's not restricted to be used with a table view. Do not use it inside a method, use the FRC in the class where you will be using your data.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use it inside the carsOrderedByDate method? Unfortunately that would put me back to square one. Maybe I have 30 places where I need to access a person's cars in that order. I would need to provide this code 30 times. Why not just add it to Person as carsOrderedByDate?

Comment: Well, I do not now much about your architecture, but it seems like something to be declared where this is going to be accessed, but there  is nothing wrong when using it as a property of your Person and using the nsmanagedobjectcontext of your Person instance.

Answer (score 1):

A fetched property is basically a fetch request. I am not aware of ways to add sort descriptors to these properties in the GUI, but I may be wrong. But why not just create a fetch request in your `carsByDatePurchased` method and provide a sort descriptor? It returns an array or the results (which you can wrap cheaply in an `NSOrderedSet` with `copyItems:` flag set to no).

Comment: What is the difference between this and simply accessing self.cars and applying the sort descriptor? Why would I benefit from using another fetch request in cardsByDatePurchased instead of just using self.cars?

Comment: Because the sort is performed on the database level, instead of memory after a fetch from the database.

Comment: Should I fetch all cars and use a predicate to restrict them to person == self? Or can I re-use self.cars in any way?

Comment: Self cars gives you all the cars that are linked to this person, the equivalent of performing a fetch with person equality. So you should test for person equality (`person` being the inverse relationship of `cars`) and add the sort descriptors to sort the data in the DB engine.

Comment: I'm sorry to make you spell it out for me, but 'test for person equality' means use an NSPredicate on the fetch, right? Or I should filter the results after the fetch (remembering that performance is my main objective)

Comment: Yes, it means exactly that, an NSPredicate.

Comment: So far, fetching the cars each time is proving much more expensive than accessing self.cars and applying a sort descriptor, but I will continue experimenting.

Comment: Is sorting always performed on the database level? I know that fetch request doesn't re-fetch from database objects that are already present in managed object context.

Comment: Sorting is performed on the database if you provide an `NSSortDescriptor` before fetching. You can test this by enabling debug and seeing the query sent to SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"DataRecord" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *obj in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", [obj valueForKey:@"name"]);
    NSLog(@"Info: %@", [obj valueForKey:@"info"]);
    NSLog(@"Number: %@", [obj valueForKey:@"number"]);
    NSLog(@"Create Date: %@", [obj valueForKey:@"createDate"]);
    NSLog(@"Last Update: %@", [obj valueForKey:@"updateDate"]);
}
NSManagedObject *obj = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
[self displayManagedObject:obj];
selectedObject = obj;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: If it's not an answer to the question, it shouldn't be there in the first place. On Stack Overflow, answers must provide a solution to the question.