# Multiple relationships between the same NSManagedObjects

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data, nssortdescriptor

An `Author` has multiple `Books`, both of which are `NSManagedObjects` modeled as a one-to-many relationship using Core Data. 20% of the time I just need to know how many books an author has written, so I check `author.books`.

40% of the time I need this data by order of date published, and 40% of the time I need it ordered by title. Multiple classes will want to access these ordered lists.

**Question 1**

Is it reasonable to add two additional methods to `Author : NSManagedObject`? Since I need to request them from multiple places, it seems smarter than sorting the NSSet each time in the class making the request. I.e:

```
@property NSSet *books; //core data generated - just returns the unordered set
- (NSArray *)booksByDate //applies an NSSortDescriptor to self.books, returns an NSArray
- (NSArray *)booksByTitle //applies an NSSortDescriptor to self.books, returns an NSArray
```

**Question 2**

Using the `NSSortDescriptor` has proven expensive, with an impact on UI performance. Ideally, I would like to try using the new(ish) `NSOrderedSet` to model the relationship as ordered, to see if there is a performance benefit. But I can't really pick which way to order the relationship, since whichever I choose (by date or by title) will be non-optimal 40& of the time. Not to mention that I may want to add more sorted variants later.

Is there some way I can have the best of both worlds, and store the relationship 3 times in my Core Data model? Once for the unordered relationship (`NSSet`), and once each for the ordered relationships (`NSOrderedSet`). I would only consider this if keeping all three properties in line with each other could be automatic - perhaps by tweaking how the `NSManagedObject` add/deletes/updates its Books. For example, I would like to somehow customize `author.addBook` to also insert the same book (in the correct location) into `author.booksByDate` and `author.booksByTitle`. And probably hide the

Is something like this possible? Advised? Remember, my main goal is to speed up retrieval of the ordered lists - I am willing to sacrifice write times for inserts/updates/deletes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try to do the sorting when making the request for the sorted books. If you are presenting this list on a UITableView or a similar interface element, you can use NSFetchedResultsController and its cache system to have your list of sorted books cache. This means that when you try to access the books sorted by dates/titles, the calculation to determine the order of the books is already cached, and your list will be generated faster. I offered a similar solution to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016624/fetched-property-in-core-data/13018036#comment17669164_13018036).